# phone number prefix

Tags: phone-number

How would I take a phone number like: 15556667777 and some how get its country code (prefix, the 1).. But, the issue is.. I will have to be able to get ANY numbers country prefix from any phone number. So whether it be UK, AU, US, any INTL country.

Comment: Are you looking for anything other than the answer that was provided? If so, please specify what in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a pretty complicated parsing, with lots of exceptions. You should try some libraries for this purpose:

Google's library:
http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/
(Java and JavaScript versions)

There's a python port:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers/3.3a1